# Name conflict in Doctrine after changing database name

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

Since I changed  my main database name in Symfony, I cannot get things to work
as some part of Doctrine (I still haven't found out which) is still stuck with
the old name despite all my updates.

Here are the updates I tried :

- Using `php bin/console doctrine:database:drop` --force followed by 
  `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` to try to "restart from scratch"
- Destroying `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` and putting the new database
  name in `app/config/parameters.yml`

  - Invoking `php bin/console cache:clear` and `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` and `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query` and `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result`

What did I forget to update ?

UPDATE : the current answer suggests using `php bin/console doctrine:schema:create` but does not specify when I should do it. A "restart from scratch" procedure would go something like this :

```
 1. php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force 
 2. php bin/console doctrine:database:create
 3. php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle:MyEntity
 4. php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
 5. php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

Where should I insert `php bin/console doctrine:schema:create` in this
sequence ?

Answer (score 0):

Create schema using doctrine:schema:create Check for any errors occuring. You need to establish if there is a configuration error or just sync issue
EDIT:
If you have already code with entites you dont need to run step 3,
just create schema instead. Use phpmyadmin to see what is happening on the database side to establis if database/tables are created. As long as you have correct settings on the both sides eg. user set in databse with create db privillages and same user in config file symfony side all should work correctly.